# Already filled QSet as optional parameter

Tags: c++, qt, optional-parameters

How to write a function signature to use a optional `QSet` parameter with a already filled `QSet` as default value.

I've tried this but it won't work! :(

```
enum MyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four
};

void function(int i, QSet<MyEnum> MySet = QSet<MyEnum>() << One << Two << Four);
```

I also found this approach:

```
QSet<MyEnum> const& foo();
void function(int i, QSet<MyEnum> MySet = foo());
```

But, I'm not happy this this.

---

**Environment:**

> Qt: 5.9.6
>   C++: 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use initializer-list for default parameter like this:

```
void function(int i, QSet<int> MySet = { 1, 2, 3 });
```

---

**UPDATE**:

With `enum class`, it also works fine.

Here's the example:

```
enum class MyEnum : unsigned int
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR
};

void function(int i, QSet<MyEnum> MySet = { MyEnum::ONE, MyEnum::TWO });
```

Comment: @Marcus: What is your Qt version? And, which C++ standard are you using?

Comment: Can't you use a `std::set` instead? That one *does* have an [initializer list constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: QSet also has a the ctor with initializer-list (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qset.html#QSet-1).

Comment: @Marcus: With Qt 5.10.1 and C++11 works just fine. Can you post that part along with the compiler message in your question? That would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think it is important but i don't use **int** as datatype but a **Enum** , sorry

Comment: @Marcus: An `enum` or `enum class`? Can you update your question with your use-case? Because with for `int` it is working just fine.

Comment: @Marcus, the solution worked for me pretty well (whether I am using ints or enums) on Qt 5.9.1. According to the documentation, QSet's constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list` has been there since Qt5.1. This means that it should for you (at least for the example in your question). Can you prepare an MCVE that shows the new error you are getting when you use this solution?

Comment: with **int** it works ... so i switch to **int** and cast it to **enum** when needed, thx

Comment: @Marcus: I've added an example with `enum class` also. It works fine. You won't have to do any type-casting.

Answer (score 2):

Imho it is not nice to have the initialization in the function signature (especially if you put the declaration in a header and the implementation in a source file it can be annoying). You can use `std::optional`. Simpler example (as I dont have Qt available atm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

void foo(std::optional<int> x = {}) {
    if (!x) { x = 3; } // or get the default value from somewhere
    std::cout << x.value();
}

int main()
{
    foo(23);
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Python-style mutable default arguments :)